# How to share my trip with Google Maps programmatically?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

With the introduction of trip sharing inside Google Maps, I wonder if there is a way to share my trip with others programmatically. I am building a mobile app and I think it might be possible to send a link to other users and maybe send my location to Google Maps via its API.

Comment: Hi awavi, have you tried reading this blog? https://www.blog.google/products/maps/share-your-trips-and-real-time-location-google-maps/

Comment: Yes. I am looking how to do so programmatically

Answer (score 3):

Currently you cannot do this via Google Maps APIs.

There is a feature request in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62938530

Feel free to star the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications.

Comment: They ask me for a google.com email, and I do not work there.

Comment: I fixed the link. Try it again.

Comment: Thanks I added a comment what else can I do to incentive them?

Comment: Star the issue, the number of stars is one of the factors that taken into account to prioritize feature requests. If the feature is not widely demanded the priority typically is low.